# (location = location * 2.0) Doesn't work as (location *= 2.0)

Tags: python, scripting, objects

Why this code works:

```
import bpy

location = bpy.context.object.location
location *= 2.0
```

And this doesn't:

```
import bpy

location = bpy.context.object.location
location = location * 2.0
```

And just to make things a little bit more confuse, why this works?

```
import bpy

bpy.context.object.location = bpy.context.object.location * 2.0
```

The three code are essentially the same thing, but only two of them work.

As far as I know **A *= 2** is the same as **A = A * 2**. But why one works and the other doesn't when I use the "location" attribution?

Comment: I _think_ this is  a Python question, not a Blender question: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15376520/11419356)..

Comment: ...further to above, In example 1 location is a reference to the objects bound location vector, and the *= statement is the equivalent of example 3.  In example 2, the `location` on the RHS of eq is `ob.location` but the result (LHS) is a new vector object, no longer refering to the blender object, that has the value of double the objects location vector.  Print it out and you will see the value is as expected, but since it is no longer the vector bound to the object it does not move the object.